# My NFS drives do not mount at startup

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, nfs

After a reboot, my NFS drives do not mount automatically, I need to manually do:

`sudo mount -a`

What is wrong? My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b59667cf-c443-4832-9286-0856ca9e7a35 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

192.168.1.96:/nfs/Backups /media/iomega nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.96:/nfs /media/ix2-6 nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.97:/nfs /media/ix2-4 nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.97:/nfs/Videos /media/ix2-4-videos nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.97:/nfs/Documents/Archives /media/ix2-4-archives nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.92:/nfs/Videos /media/wd-ex2/videos nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.92:/nfs/Documents /media/wd-ex2/Documents nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.92:/nfs/Sounds /media/wd-ex2/Sounds nfs nolock 0 0
192.168.1.92:/nfs/USB_TrekStor_DS_maxi_g.u_q_1 /media/wd-ex2/usb1 nfs nolock 0 0
```